# else path not taken on a singleton class constructor

Tags: jestjs

Disclaimer: part of an assignment on testing. Given this class, I am supposed to write two tests for it but I was told I didn't cover all edges. I noticed else path not taken on the constructor. What do I do about it?

```
import { Proccessor } from '../../services/processor';

class processForm {


  constructor() {
    if (!processForm.instance) {
      processForm.instance = this;
    }
    return processForm.instance;
  }

  setData(data) {
    this.Proccessor.prepareData(data);
  }
  resetData(){
      this.Proccessor.resetData();
  }
}

const SetForm = new processForm();

export default SetForm;
```

leaving aside the mocks that are in place, I did it like this:

```
    import SetForm from './SetForm';
    describe('Process data', () => {

       test('can set data', () => {});
       test('can reset data', () => {});
     });
```

my tests pass but I notice the following warning:

```
    else path not taken
```

on

```
  constructor() {
   **E** if (!processForm.instance) {
      processForm.instance = this;
    }
    return processForm.instance;
  }
```

While I am not allowed to edit the class itself, I did try /* istanbul igore else */ which doesn't have an effect. What coverage am I missing exactly?

Comment: There's a holy-war going on in the JS developer scene about whether or not the constructor you have should be considered legit or not (it certainly isn't GoF-style Singleton, even if it does work, because it violates the expectation that the `new` operator always returns a reference to a separate object-identity). May I ask what the backstory is here?

Comment: Are you allowed to export the `processForm` class differently, without changing the class itself?

Comment: @Dai the chapter is about unit testing meant for mocking mainly (the imported service) but I am told i didn't cover all edge cases.

Comment: @xdhmoore I am not sure but I can still submit i think as long as i don't change the provided class fundamentally.

Answer (score 0):

A couple thoughts:

The processForm file is exporting a SetForm object. Unless I'm mistaken, this means that the only place that constructor is ever called is on this line:

```
const SetForm = new processForm();
```

Since the object SetForm is exported, the constructor only gets called once, and that if statement you mentioned only gets called when the constructor is called more than once. So every time you `import SetForm`, you get the same object, and don't call the constructor.

An alternative, is to export the constructor itself:

```
export default processForm as SetForm;
```

Then when you import it, you would have to call new on it:

```
import SetForm from './SetForm';
let myObj1 = new SetForm();
let myObj2 = new SetForm();
```

If you call the constructor twice, then you should end up invoking that code. I suppose that this is all assuming that that if block was the place your professor was referring to.

I'm not an expert on the new import mechanisms, and I'm sure there are situations where you'd want to export and then import the same object like that (maybe for a singleton pattern), but in the few times I've used them, I've exported a constructor so that I could import it and call `new` on it to create new objects.

As a side note, you can pass in the `--coverage` flag to jest (or set it in the config) and it will give you a coverage percentage, which can be helpful.